# creating Rdoc for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

I would like to generate a documentation to my rails (2.3.8) project. When I tried

```
rake doc:rails
rake doc:rerails
```

It creates documentation for all the classes including standard ruby classes and all the ruby files in vendor directory (plugins etc..)

How can I create rdoc documentation only for ruby classes, files in following directories

1. app folder (all the models, controllers and views)
2. config folder
3. lib folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I added this to my Rakefile;

```
RDoc::Task.new :rdoc do |rdoc|
  rdoc.main = "README.rdoc"

  rdoc.rdoc_files.include("README.rdoc", "doc/*.rdoc", "app/**/*.rb", "lib/*.rb", "config/**/*.rb")
  #change above to fit needs

  rdoc.title = "App Documentation"
  rdoc.options << "--all" 
end
```

Then run;

```
rake rdoc
```

Check out the RDoc::Task docs for more http://rdoc.rubyforge.org/RDoc/Task.html

Admittedly I am on a rails 3 app, but I think this works the same.

Comment: This didn't work for me (not surprising for a 7+ year-old answer!) but [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804474/199712) did.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rake doc:app` to generate documentation for the app.

Quoting from section 2.4 of [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html):

> The doc: namespace has the tools to generate documentation for your
>   app, API documentation, guides. Documentation can also be stripped
>   which is mainly useful for slimming your codebase, like if you're
>   writing a Rails application for an embedded platform.
>
> rake doc:app generates documentation for your application in doc/app.
>   rake doc:guides generates Rails guides in doc/guides. rake doc:rails
>   generates API documentation for Rails in doc/api.

Comment: When I tried this command it had no effect. The quoted section also seems to have been removed from the linked page.

Comment: It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804474/199712) is what works today.