# RDoc just my own application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rdoc

Is there a way to stop RDoc from going higher than the current directory? i just tried

```
rdoc -O -x ../
```

but this also stopped it from parsing relative pathes in subdirectories; what I really need is something like:

If absolute path of App is /foo/bar/MyAppDir/, just RDoc all sources inside and below /foo/bar/MyAppDir/ without parsing /foo/bar/OtherRepository/ from wich some classes derive and get functions I dont want to document.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help - [creating Rdoc for a rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279953/creating-rdoc-for-a-rails-app)

You could probably include the files/directories that you just need to be parsed. This should work same way for both rails 2 and 3.